# Are in-app tabs bad practice?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, web-app

I have certain advanced use cases of a web-app that can be handled by allowing users to open details of items in new tabs (i.e. a single page app with an unlimited row of in-app tabs which imitate the behaviour of browser tabs).

1. Given that "tabs inside tabs" isn't the best user experience, is it bad practice to imitate browser tabs within a single browser tab?
2. Opening item details in new tabs forces users to understand and manage tabs. Are non-technical users easily confused by complexity of tabs?

Comment: are the tabs truly tabs in that they will 'flip' the content immediately client-side? I ask because if they are instead server-side requests, then they aren't quite as useful as tabs and perhaps might be better served via a different navigation UI.

Comment: @DA01 yes they are true tabs that load data dynamically via ajax, allowing users to flip back and forth as needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabs within tabs are confusing because it's hard to figure out where you are; each layer of tabs ads a spacial dimension. For more info on what makes tabs within tabs problematic (and how to avoid the trouble), see [Is there evidence to suggest that designing tabs within tabs creates a bad user experience?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5136/is-there-evidence-to-suggest-that-designing-tabs-within-tabs-creates-a-bad-user)

However as you note, tabs are common in webpages. Why wouldn't these tabs be fine?

The problem of "tabs within tabs" is obviated by the **clear distinction between page and browser**. Your user is almost certainly *very* familiar with where the browser tabs stop and the page starts, unless you're *trying* to make the tabs identical to the user's browser's specific tab style, your app's tabs will be in a clearly different context from the browser tabs.

Since the context between browser and page is clear, you're losing the big problem of tabs within tabs; nested, branched navigation.

Take a look at [Tabs, Used Right](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/tabs.html). Specifically you're using tabs for view-switching, and presumably in-app there's really **only *one* row of tabs**. As long as you're keeping to one row of in-app tabs it shouldn't be a problem because contextually it's quite clear that those are your apps tabs, and there's no navigating back and forth between multiple layers of tabs in the same app.